# How to exclude a folder in svn checkout in maven?

Tags: svn, maven-2, build-automation, maven-scm

Im using maven to checkout some projects. I don't want maven to checkout a folder. But it seems to ignore the excludes tag in configuration.

This is the svn structure:

```
trunk/  
|-- folder_to_include  
`-- folder_to_ignore
```

And here it goes a sample of the pom.xml:

```
<execution>  
  <id>checkout_application</id>  
  <configuration>  
    <connectionUrl>hostname</connectionUrl>  
    <checkoutDirectory>checkout_folder</checkoutDirectory>  
    <excludes>folder_to_ignore</excludes>  
  </configuration>  
  <phase>process-resources</phase>  
  <goals>  
     <goal>checkout</goal>  
  </goals>  
</execution>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice the same behaviour. I suggest filing this issue in http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM.